# Getting values from a custom indicator

Tags: mql4, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to get values from a custom indicator which has the input parameters shown on the image.

[image]
Below is the code I tried:

```
double value=iCustom(NULL,0,"Market\\My Indi",
         "",
         2,
         1.0,
         "",
         0,
         PERIOD_M15,
         PERIOD_M30,
         PERIOD_H1,
         PERIOD_H4,
         PERIOD_D1,
         PERIOD_W1,
         "",
         70.0,
         -70.0,
         "",
         false,
         true,
         true,
         "",
         20000
         ,0,1);
```

I am trying to get this value on every bar close but I only get 120.0 which is very different from the actual indicator values that run on other charts.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

your are calling buffer#0 - make sure you really need that buffer (or call same function for buffers 0-7 or 0-15 and write them all, if indicator doesnt have more buffers you will see EMPTY_VALUE (in digits), but you will see all the buffers. Maybe first buffer(#0) has something hidden and when you see line#1 - it can be buffer_id=1 or 2 not 0.

alternative is to ask the seller, or check if there is a supplementary file from the seller with instructions on hom to call each line

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will look into that buffer issue you mentioned. Other than that, do you think there's a problem with the calling order of the input parameters based on the image I provided?